# Trying to use regex to match the "?si=" on YouTube share links

Tags: regex, youtube, url, url-rewriting

I want to match the `?si=` on the end of YouTube links using Regex so that I can filter submitted links to remove the `?si=` and what comes after.

I want to exclusively match that ID, and not anything that could potentially come after, such as `?t=300` to start 5 minutes into a video, a space/newline/closed parenthesis/less than symbol following a link, or anything else that could potentially come after said link.

Example:

```
[Check this out!](https://youtu.be/LY2xiOqi9gU?si=WzYuT7GK_IULnUPQ)
```

Check this video out:

```
<https://youtu.be/LY2xiOqi9gU?si=WzYuT7GK_IULnUPQ>
```

Check this out!

```
https://youtu.be/LY2xiOqi9gU?si=WzYuT7GK_IULnUPQ It's pretty cool.
```

Etc…

I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Comment: Hello, for which app/engine? It's pointeless to ask without that data. Different apps utilize different engines.

Comment: If your regex engine supports lookbehind, use: `(?<=\?si=)\w+`

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex would be `si=([\w_]*)`.

The id is to be found in group match 1.

Comment: `$ sed -re 's/si=([\w_]*)//g' <sed.txt` indeed removes the `?si=...` -portion... Now; how come the `?` is included?

Comment: Attempting the same at https://regex101.com/ - does NOT remove the `?` before `si`.  ==> https://regex101.com/r/7OS5Y6/1

Comment: @Hannu: I don't understand - the group is the result, no need to remove anything.

Comment: well, the intention was to remove `?si=---` according to OP. I don't understand how the `?` before `si` gets caught - that is my initial comment, well - not very important.